# Use one if statement instead of multiple

Tags: ios, xcode

For talking sakes lets say you've got 5 floats, which are all stored in a single float and are all positions of an image. Now how would I - if even possible - see which of those five floats are equal to 500, and if there is any floats equal, find which ones are and give them a new position.

```
-(void)Position
{
ObjectOne.center = CGPointMake(ObjectOne.center.x, 500);
ObjectFour.center = CGPointMake(ObjectFour.center.x, 500);

Float[1] = ObjectOne.center.y;
Float[2] = ObjectTwo.center.y;
Float[3] = ObjectThree.center.y;
Float[4] = ObjectFour.center.y;
Float[5] = ObjectFive.center.y;
[self Cheaking];
}

-(void)Checking
{
if(Float[1 to 5] == 500) {
Find objects which are equal.
ObjectWhichIsEqual.center = CGPointMake(225, ObjectWhichIsEqual.center.y)
ObjectWhichIsEqualTwo.center = CGPointMake(225, ObjectWhichIsEqualTwo.center.y) } 
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Instead of using a float I'm now using a NSNumber for each coordinate and storing them in a NSMutableSet. Right now I'm using a NSPredicate to see if there is any numbers equal to 500, however I cannot seem to use the one if statement to do this. The reason why I'm using one if statement to do this because I'll have to do loads of if statements example:

```
if(ObjectOne.center.y == 500) {
ObjectOne.center = CGPointMake(225, ObjectOne.center.y);
}

if(ObjectTwo.center.y == 500) {
ObjectTwo.center = CGPointMake(225, ObjectTwo.center.y);
} ect...
```

Where as this is one if statement for them all, however I don't know how to finish it.

```
-(void)Position
{
ObjectOne.center = CGPointMake(0, 500);
ObjectFour.center = CGPointMake (0, 500);
NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:ObjectOne.center.y];
NSNumber *two = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:ObjectTwo.center.y];
NSNumber *three = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:ObjectThree.center.y];
NSNumber *four = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:ObjectFour.center.y];
NSNumber *five = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:ObjectFive.center.y];

NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableset setWithObjects:one, two, three, four, five, nil];
[self checking];
}

-(void)Checking
{
NSPredicate *pre;
pre = [NSPredicte predicateWithFormat:"SELF == %i", 500];
[set filterUsingPredicate:pre]; //line not working
if(pre == true) {find which objects are equal and move them // have no clue how to do this
    }
}
```

I know NSPredicate is probably the wrong way to go, so is there anything like it which will solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like a good plan. What's the problem?

Comment: Is Float an array? And do you only want to find out if the floats are equal if they equal 500? And where do the coordinates come in? I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: Float is a 1D array - or at least I think - float Float[5]; -

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do the 'Cheaking' method. From Float[1 to 5] part and find out which objects have the equal position.

Comment: So lets say you've got a screen, with five boxes on it, to which they all have a different Y coordinate. Now I have put 500 as two of the objects Y coordinates to make this simpler but in reality it's more complicated, but that's not the problem. In the IF statement I want to check if any of the objects have a Y coordinate of 500 hence the array for the float. Then if there is objects which have the Y coordinate I want to then find out which objects it is, and move those objects.

Comment: Do you know what a "loop" is??

Comment: Yup, but that won't solve the problem. Using a loop will practically be the same as using a NSPredicate. It'll find something is equal, but it won't tell me which Object is equal.

Comment: If you set a variable to identify the equal object, you will know which object is equal.

Answer (score 1):

It is the **object** you want to reference not the **float**. Even when you get the **float** equal to 500 there is no way to reference the **object**. You would be better to put the objects in an **NSMutableArray** or **NSMutableSet** and then you can iterate through each **object** accordingly. You can also get the size of the collection which makes things easier.

Just a suggestion - *(as I personally try to avoid a polling approach)*

Depending on what exactly you are trying to do, consider overriding the **setter** for the **center** property. (you may need to subclass)

something like -

```
-(void)setCenter:(CGPoint)center {
     // check if y == 500 here first and do what needs to be done...
     if (center.y == 500) { 
           //do stuff... center.x = 250; etc...
      }
     _center = center;
}
```